# Phalcon 1.3 Resultset Not Storing changes in items

Tags: php, phalcon

Can anyone explain me how phalcon working with resultset? When I walk throw resultset and change some items properties, and after that I walk throw again - all my changes lost.

What I doing wrong?

Sample code from controller:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $content = "<h2>Test update resultset w/o saving data</h2>";

    /** @var OrdersItems[] $items */
    $items = OrdersItems::find("external_item_id = 'Test'");

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $content .= $item->name . ': supplier_id update from ' . $item->supplier_id . ' to ' . $i++ . "<br />";
        $item->supplier_id = $i;
    }

    $content .= "<hr /><h2>Walk again throw items</h2>";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $content .= $item->name . ': supplier_id = ' . $item->supplier_id . "<br />";
    }

    return $this->response->setContent($content);
}
```

Result output:

```
Test update resultset w/o saving data
Autogenerated item 1: supplier_id update from 5 to 1
Autogenerated item 2: supplier_id update from 4 to 2
Autogenerated item 3: supplier_id update from 3 to 3
Autogenerated item 4: supplier_id update from 2 to 4
Autogenerated item 5: supplier_id update from 1 to 5

Walk again throw items
Autogenerated item 1: supplier_id = 5
Autogenerated item 2: supplier_id = 4
Autogenerated item 3: supplier_id = 3
Autogenerated item 4: supplier_id = 2
Autogenerated item 5: supplier_id = 1
```

Comment: You are not saving your changes.

Comment: I need to get this changes during one process run, so no need to save them. BTW if I save them - I'll also get same situation on this process run, only on next run (reload) I'll get saved values, and this is exact what I ask

Comment: `$items = $items->toArray()` and work on tables. Should remember what you have set during first run ;)

Comment: Yes - if I will get this as array it would work, but if I use array:
1. I need to control additional things like to use this param as pointer / reference in called methods
2. This would take additional memory, as using copy of resultset

As for me it's not normal and it looks like a some kind of bug, but I thought may be I don't know some magic/rules phalcon working

Comment: Anyway if you want to use it this way, you will be forced to clone/convert or use additional methods to gather dirsty state. It's on you if you choose arrays, or solve everything in first loop run. Btw, youre printing `$i++` and assigning `$i` - velues in that block will be different.